# How to execute shell scripting in md file

Tags: shell, sed, grep, markdown

We have a MarkDown file where we are storing versions of multiple components.
Below is the sample .md file

```
component1=1.2
components2=2.3
component3=`cat file1 | grep 'App_Version' | grep -P '(?<==).*' && rm -rf file1`
```

Here the component3 version is dynamic, so we are executing the command to get the version.

Need help on accomplishing this in correct way.

Answer (score 2):

Markdown is not a scripting language, so you probably need one form or another of preprocessing. Example with GNU `m4` (but any preprocessor with similar capabilities would do the job):

```bash
$ cat sample.m4
m4_changequote(`"""', `"""')m4_dnl
component1=1.2
components2=2.3
component3=m4_esyscmd("""grep -Po '(?<=App_Version=).*' file1 && rm -f file1""")m4_dnl
component4=foo

$ cat file1
App_Version=4.0.2

$ m4 -P sample.m4 > sample.md

$ cat sample.md
component1=1.2
components2=2.3
component3=4.0.2
component4=foo

$ ls file1
ls: cannot access 'file1': No such file or directory
```

Explanations:

- The `-P` option of `m4` modifies all builtin macro names so they all start with the `m4_` prefix. It is not absolutely needed but it makes the source code easier to read.
- The `sample.m4` file is your source file, the one you edit. The:

  `m4 -P sample.m4 > sample.md`

  command preprocesses the source file to produce the markdown file.
- The `m4_changequote` macro at the beginning of `sample.m4` changes the quotes that `m4` uses for text strings. Use any left and right quotes you want (`"""` in our example) as long as it is not used in your markdown text.
- `m4_dnl` is the macro that suppresses the rest of the line, including the newline character.
- `m4_esyscmd("""cmd""")` substitutes the output of the `cmd` shell script.

Note: I assumed that you wanted `grep -Po '(?<=App_Version=).*' file1` instead of `cat file1 | grep 'App_Version' | grep -P '(?<==).*'` which looks like several anti-patterns at once.

Answer (score 0):

if your code is inside code block, try to parse out the code block and then execute it as is.
this is a bash function to do so

````bash
function mbe() {
  if [ -f "$1" ]; then
    cat $1 | # print the file
    sed -n '/```bash/,/```/p' | # get the bash code blocks
    sed 's/```bash//g' | #  remove the ```bash
    sed 's/```//g' | # remove the trailing ```
    sed '/^$/d' | # remove empty lines
    /usr/bin/env sh ; # execute the command
  else
    echo "${1} is not valid" ;
  fi
}
````

source: https://gist.github.com/gmolveau/67d10dfaea1fdd729865b2f8d46f7488